# Primary GPT table corrupt (RAID-1 and mounted as /home) stopping me reinstalling Linux

Tags: linux, raid, raid-1

Env: `Linux TRANQUILITY 5.3.18-150300.59.49-preempt #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Feb 7 14:40:20 UTC 2022 (77d9d02) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` Also OpenSuse Leap 15.3 with KDE Plasma 5

When I run the OS install from a USB stick I get as far as the partition check, where it bombs out with: `/usr/bin/udevadm /dev/sdd1 could not be found (failed)` - (I can't recall the precise error text, without re-running the install process but this is the gist of it)

Last year (April 2021) I had a problem when I lost my `/home` data and had to take the non-RAIDed disk to a data recovery company. From memory, I think it turned out to be a GPT error, which was only expensive and not astronomical to fix (happy to pay to get my data safe). I had them transfer all the `/home` data from that disk to one of two 1TB WD Black disks I bought. I setup RAID-1 with the two new disks and this seemingly worked fine *until recently*!

---

**This context section on why I'm trying to reinstall (between the horizontal lines) may/may not be relevant?**

Weird things stared happening, I have no idea whether they're related but they seem quite systemic - like:

1. Firefox tabs started crashing immediately on certain sites, which I
   thought/think might be a Firefox bug
2. Python stopped working to the
   extent that unrelated programs failed (Libre-Office mainly - keeps
   entering recovery) but FreeCAD (largely Python based) still worked
3. Corel AftershotPro won't start because of a missing/incorrect
   version library (which is still there)

Lots of the fixes I tried seemed to come back to Python. In the end I removed Python which uninstalled a lot of key OS stuff (particularly the GUI) and then I re-installed it (along with most of the items that had been auto uninstalled. Even that didn't work, so I thought I'd reinstall the OS - thinking my `/home` data would be safe. As I mentioned this doesn't appear to be the case and it's stopping my reinstall to stabilise my computer.

---

Tried:

```
lsblk
<snipped the loop devices>
sda             8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─sda1          8:1    0 931.5G  0 part  
  └─md127       9:127  0 931.5G  0 raid1 
    └─md127p1 259:0    0 931.5G  0 part  /home
sdb             8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk  
└─sdb1          8:17   0   1.8T  0 part  
  └─cr-auto-1 254:0    0   1.8T  0 crypt /china2
sdc             8:32   0 111.8G  0 disk  
├─sdc1          8:33   0   148M  0 part  
├─sdc2          8:34   0   100G  0 part  /
├─sdc3          8:35   0     2G  0 part  
└─sdc4          8:36   0     2G  0 part  
sdd             8:48   0 931.5G  0 disk  
sde             8:64   0   1.8T  0 disk  
└─sde1          8:65   0   1.8T  0 part  /chinaPhotos
```

Note `sda/sda1/md127/md127p1` is mounted here as `/home`

I'd guess `sda` & `sdd` are the contributing physical RAID devices and `sdd` is the broken one?

I have tried the following: (which shows `/home` is `/dev/md127p1`)

```
df -h
Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                          4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs                             7.8G  243M  7.5G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs                             3.1G  335M  2.8G  11% /run
tmpfs                             4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdc2                         100G   38G   63G  38% /
/dev/sdc2                         100G   38G   63G  38% /.snapshots
/dev/sdc2                         100G   38G   63G  38% /boot/grub2/i386-pc
/dev/sdc2                         100G   38G   63G  38% /boot/grub2/x86_64-efi
/dev/sdc2                         100G   38G   63G  38% /opt
/dev/sdc2                         100G   38G   63G  38% /root
/dev/sdc2                         100G   38G   63G  38% /srv
/dev/sdc2                         100G   38G   63G  38% /tmp
/dev/sdc2                         100G   38G   63G  38% /var
/dev/sdc2                         100G   38G   63G  38% /usr/local
/dev/sdb1                         1.8T  1.7T   94G  95% /chinaPhotos
/dev/md127p1                      932G  402G  530G  44% /home
<snipped loop devices>
/dev/mapper/cr-auto-1             1.9T  1.5T  399G  79% /china2
tmpfs                             1.6G   72K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdm                          3.4M  3.3M  116K  97% /run/media/░░░░/SBEAM
/dev/sdn                          1.6M   24K  1.6M   2% /run/media/░░░░/UPDATE
192.168.░░░.░░░:/volume1/DataBackup  2.7T  2.3T  492G  83% /░░░░░
<snipped loop devices>
```

Finally, I've tried

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md*  
mdadm: /dev/md does not appear to be an md device
/dev/md127:
           Version : 1.0
     Creation Time : Sun Apr 25 17:58:55 2021
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 976761344 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 976761344 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Sun Mar  6 19:26:29 2022
             State : clean, degraded 
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : any:home
              UUID : 75959fa2:f25b6088:7a9e9a80:c1f38480
            Events : 3183874

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       -       0        0        1      removed
/dev/md127p1:
           Version : 1.0
     Creation Time : Sun Apr 25 17:58:55 2021
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 976760303 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 976761344 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Sun Mar  6 19:26:29 2022
             State : clean, degraded 
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : any:home
              UUID : 75959fa2:f25b6088:7a9e9a80:c1f38480
            Events : 3183874

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       -       0        0        1      removed
```

The install process identifies `/dev/sdd` as the problem but seems to have the same problem as `fdisk` below.

```
fdisk /dev/sdd

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.36.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.
```

and

```
fdisk  /dev/sda

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.36.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): v
No errors detected.
Header version: 1.0
Using 1 out of 128 partitions.
A total of 2014 free sectors is available in 1 segment.
```

The computer is mostly working OK and I've backed up most of /home's data but updates are backing up and I can't reinstall safely.

In terms of hardware, physically removed each of the RAID disks in turn (PC off first, obvs) - one of the disks makes no difference to the boot (all working on reboot) but removing the other stops the boot process, so I guess the second is the working RAID `/dev/sda` - `/home` disk and the former is the 'broken' `/dev/sdd` one! I also tried swapping the broken one to the working one's SATA cable in case that was the problem but nada!

**What further diagnostics/actions can I run to:**

- see if my supposition about that disk being the faulty one is correct
- find out what's wrong with it and whether it's a terminal or fixable problem (there's a 3 or 5 (?) yr warranty on these disks but they're just less than 1 yr old.)
- format it or otherwise recover it and add it back into the RAID1 array (or should I get it replaced?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it using `gdisk /dev/sdd`

```
gdisk /dev/sdd
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Caution: invalid main GPT header, but valid backup; regenerating main header
from backup!

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************

Command (? for help): r

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): b

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): ?
b       use backup GPT header (rebuilding main)
c       load backup partition table from disk (rebuilding main)
d       use main GPT header (rebuilding backup)
e       load main partition table from disk (rebuilding backup)
f       load MBR and build fresh GPT from it
g       convert GPT into MBR and exit
h       make hybrid MBR
i       show detailed information on a partition
l       load partition data from a backup file
m       return to main menu
o       print protective MBR data
p       print the partition table
q       quit without saving changes
t       transform BSD disklabel partition
v       verify disk
w       write table to disk and exit
x       extra functionality (experts only)
?       print this menu

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): b

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): v

No problems found. 2014 free sectors (1007.0 KiB) available in 1
segments, the largest of which is 2014 (1007.0 KiB) in size.

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): b

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/sdd.
The operation has completed successfully.
```

Comment: I followed the instructions here https://www.howtoforge.com/replacing_hard_disks_in_a_raid1_array to add the disk back into the RAID array. Seems to have worked

Answer (score 1):

The gdisk/fdisk fix does not work, delete this again if you wish but I have tried to use it on all 512GB devices I have and they report problem fixed. But, a recheck with g/fdisk shows the exact same error again. As I said in my now deleted post this is only showing up in 512GB devices. All my other smaller or larger 512GB SD cards, USB's and my 1T external SSD have never gave me any grief while everything at 512GBs has. Your experience may be different but this ole hardware tech sees something wrong here that does not involve hardware.